# sequelize model exclude subfield within a jsonb field

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb

I have a postgresql table structured with a jsonb field named external_data:
`external_data: {a: 1, b:2, c:3}`

I know that in sequelize model definitions, you can exclude a field by including in the options properties a defaultScope like this:

`{defaultScope: {attributes: { exclude: ['external_data'] }}`

When I do that to exclude the entire field, it works, i.e. external_data doesn't show up in returned results. However, I'd like to exclude a specific subfield. I've tried `exclude: ['external_data.b']` but that doesn't seem to work.

Does sequelize allow excluding subfields within jsonb fields? And if so, what's the proper format of the exclude attribute to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs: https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/scopes.html

> Scopes are defined in the model definition and can be finder objects, or functions returning finder objects - except for the default scope, which can only be an object

So, you can define the scope via a function that returns the finder objects so that you can implement the complex scope.

E.g.

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes, Op } from 'sequelize';

class TableA extends Model {}
TableA.init(
  {
    external_data: DataTypes.JSONB,
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'table_a',
    defaultScope: {
      attributes: { exclude: ['external_data'] },
    },
    scopes: {
      exclude(subField) {
        return {
          where: {
            external_data: {
              [subField]: {
                [Op.eq]: null,
              },
            },
          },
        };
      },
    },
  },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    // create tables
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await TableA.bulkCreate([
      { external_data: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } },
      { external_data: { a: 10, c: 30 } },
      { external_data: { a: 100 } },
    ]);
    // test
    // test case 1: exclude subfield "b"
    const result1 = await TableA.scope({ method: ['exclude', 'b'] }).findAll({ raw: true });
    console.log('result1:', result1);
    // test case 2: exclude subfield "c"
    const result2 = await TableA.scope({ method: ['exclude', 'c'] }).findAll({ raw: true });
    console.log('result2:', result2);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

The execution results:

```sh
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "table_a" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "table_a" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "table_a" ("id"   SERIAL , "external_data" JSONB, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'table_a' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "table_a" ("id","external_data") VALUES (DEFAULT,'{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}'),(DEFAULT,'{"a":10,"c":30}'),(DEFAULT,'{"a":100}') RETURNING *;
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "external_data" FROM "table_a" AS "table_a" WHERE ("table_a"."external_data"#>>'{b}') IS NULL;
result1: [ { id: 2, external_data: { a: 10, c: 30 } },
  { id: 3, external_data: { a: 100 } } ]
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "external_data" FROM "table_a" AS "table_a" WHERE ("table_a"."external_data"#>>'{c}') IS NULL;
result2: [ { id: 3, external_data: { a: 100 } } ]
```

check the database:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "table_a";
 id |      external_data
----+--------------------------
  1 | {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
  2 | {"a": 10, "c": 30}
  3 | {"a": 100}
(3 rows)
```

Dependencies versions:  `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`, `postgres:9.6`

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/node-sequelize-examples/tree/master/src/examples/stackoverflow/61053931

Comment: This is great! Thank you. Didn't realize how much power defining the scope via a function gives you :-)